# Brother Scanner does not work with macOS Catalina

Tags: macos

I have a Brother `MFC-8890 DW`.

When I upgraded to macOS Catalina, my Scanner Control Center 2 software does not work. Printer works.

Brother site says go to use the iPrint&Scan software, but this model is not supported.

Answer (score 5):

> "The Brother ControlCenter2 is not supported by macOS v10.15.
>
> Use the Brother iPrint&Scan as an alternative function."
>
> Source [Brother macOS Catalina Support Statement](https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/os/macintosh.html)

Control Center was a 32-bit application that Catalina wont run. Update MFC-8890 DW drivers provided at [Brother website](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc8890dw_all) for 10.15 support.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you how landed here looking for a way to scan files on other Brother devices that were discontinued in Catalina (10.15+), you can [verify if ICA driver is still available](https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/os/macintosh.html) for your scanner and use the `Image capture` built-in macOS app instead of Brother's ControlCenter.

Comment: What exactly needs to be done to "verify if ICA driver is still available"?

Comment: https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/os/macintosh.html - check out this compatibility table